# Is it possible to define a Maybe Function in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

I want to declare a parameter type as Maybe a function with a default value of `undefined`.

However I am getting Flow errors as neither `undefined` or `null` are considered to be of type `function`.

Is there are way to do this?

Comment: Are you setting the type as `Function` or `Function | void`/``?Function` and have you looked at the docs? https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/ Actual examples of what you've tried are important.

Comment: I've tried `?Function` and `Function | undefined`, along with the `() => void` form instead of Function. I have read the docs for `Maybe` and therefore I expected ?Function to work but then `undefined` was not accepted as a value for Function. The issue seems to be one of base types and therefore I think I might be taking the wrong approach and I'm looking for an answer in principle.

Comment: Please add code that demonstrates the code that is currently failing you, otherwise this isn't really answerable.

Comment: Would it be clearer if I phrased my question as: What is the correct way to express the type of a parameter that is a function but whose default value is undefined?

Comment: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swpsAKXAQxhgCNrcBrALjADEcDjSAfMADc4hACZgAvGByiAplELZZogJRgA3gF8gA works fine. Example code would help because it gives a common basis to work on. English descriptions are never going to be as accurate as real code, otherwise we're write code in English :P Hope that example helps though.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implement a function that executes a given function, unless the given function is undefined:

```
function maybeExecute<A: *, R>(f: ?(...args: A) => R, ...args: A): ?R {
  if (f) {
    return f(...args)
  }
}
```

That type-checks in Flow v0.64.0. The use of the `?` indicates that `f` might be `undefined` or `null`. The `if (f) { /* ... */ }` check narrows the type of `f` so that inside the body of the `if` Flow can guarantee that `f` is a function.

You can get a little fancier and declare multiple signatures to make `maybeExecute` an overloaded function like this:

```
declare function maybeExecute<A: *, R>(f: (...args: A) => R, ...args: A): R
declare function maybeExecute(f: null | void, ...args: mixed[]): void

function maybeExecute(f, ...args) {
  if (f) {
    return f(...args)
  }
}
```

With the overloaded version if Flow is able to infer that the given function was defined then it may be able to infer that the return value of `maybeExecute` is also defined.